# Access nested array in Polymer repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a `users` array like so :

```
        [{
            "name": "John",
            "surname": "McClane",
            "prefs": [{
                "Gourmande": 1,
                "Espiegle": 0
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Robert",
            "surname": "DeNiro",
            "prefs": [{
                "Gourmande": 1,
                "Espiegle": 0
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Siegfried",
            "surname": "Klause",
            "prefs": [{
                "Gourmande": 1,
                "Espiegle": 0
            }]
        }]
```

Which I access in my template like so :

```
<ul class="userlist">
    <template repeat="{{ user in users }}">
        <li class="user">
            {{user.name}} preferences are listed below : <br>
            <template repeat="{{ pref in user.prefs }}">
                - {{ pref }} <br>
                <!-- {{ pref.Gourmande }} works fine, but I want to display "Gourmande" -->
            </template>
        </li>
    </template>
</ul>
```

I am unable to iterate over the `prefs`. I've tried the above configuration, nesting template tags, using array-like notation (`user.prefs[0]`, `user.prefs.slice(0)`), all to no avail.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? What I'd like to do is ultimately to be able to list the key/value pairs of the `prefs` array (because its name/size will be changing constantly).

Thank you.

**EDIT :** I found the solution thanks to the filter you guys suggested :

```
    <template repeat="{{ pref in users.prefs }}">
        <template repeat="{{k in pref | keys}}">
            <li class="pref">
                {{ k }} : {{ pref[k] }}
            </li>
        </template>
    </template>
```

And the filter used is the one in Scott's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `template repeat` over an Object, only over an Array.

You can get close to the syntax you want like so:

```
<template repeat="{{key in object | keys}}">
  {{key}}: {{object[key]}}<br>
</template>
```

where `keys` is a filter on your prototype:

```
keys: function(object) {
  return Object.keys(object);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ciduhe/3/edit

Comment: Hi Scott, i saw that this was dicsussed in an issue on the _polymer-expression_ project and there were some votes for adding some kind of syntax for iterating over object values. Was this idea discarded because of implementation problems or is there still a chance that some day we might write something like `<template repeat="{{ key,value of object }}">`?

Comment: Here's the GitHub issue: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-expressions/issues/11

Comment: For some reason this does not work, all I get is :
`0 : [object Object]`

Comment: Scott's solution helped me solved it (updated code).

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own filter to give you an object's keys and use that to repeat over your object.

For example:

```
<polymer-element name='my-elem'>
  <template>
    <ul>
    <template repeat="{{key in obj | objectKeys}}">
      <li>{{key}} - {{obj[key]}}</li>
    </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-elem', {
      obj: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
      objectKeys: function(inp) {
        var keys = Object.keys(inp);
        // important, as Object.keys may come in arbitrary order
        keys.sort(); 
        return keys;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Try it out with this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/hozahupa/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

I found this commit of a project where they use a filter function to convert the object values into an array

[src/juicy-tree.html](https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-tile-editor/commit/20e0ac361e3a1027e9ca3ab344991431b16e0c0f)

This results in nice template expression (`<template repeat="{{ user.prefs | objectValues as pref }}">`), but the problem with this is that there is no data binding with the prefs property of the original user object.

This might be ok if you only need a one time binding.

Answer (score 0):

I used a array in array for the purpose, like this:

```
<polymer-element people="[[1, "Brad B"], [2, "Alis A"], [3, "Samon S"]]">
</polymer-element>

<polymer-select value="{{ person }}">
  <option repeat="{{person in people}}" template value="{{person[0]}}">{{person[1]}}
  </option>
</polymer-select>
```

[image]